# Covariance matrix using text file in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, statistics, covariance

I have the text file read by python.

```
import numpy as np

with open("Input2010_5a.txt", "r") as file:
for line in file:
    date, long, lat, depth, temp, sal = line.split("\t")
    line_data = []
    line_data.append(float(date))
    line_data.append(float(long))
    line_data.append(float(lat))
    line_data.append(float(depth))
    line_data.append(float(temp))
    line_data.append(float(sal))
```

As a result I've received 41 lists in such a view:

```
[2010.36, 23.2628, 59.7768, 1.0, 4.1, 6.04] #it's one of them
```

Now I need to make a ***covariance matrix*** using them. I'm not sure how to make it.

Comment: [Alina Lerner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9519024/alina-lerner) consider choosing an answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Extracting your lists from your `txt` file**

I would first extract your lists from your text file into some sort of dictionary structure, something along the lines of:

```
d = {}
with open("Input2010_5a.txt", "r") as file:
    counter = 0
    for line in file:
        date, long, lat, depth, temp, sal = line.split("\t")
        line_data = []
        line_data.append(float(date))
        line_data.append(float(long))
        line_data.append(float(lat))
        line_data.append(float(depth))
        line_data.append(float(temp))
        line_data.append(float(sal))
        d['list'+str(counter)] = line_data
        counter += 1
```

And `d` will be a dictionary looking something like this:

```
{'list0': [2010.36, 23.2628, 59.7768, 1.0, 4.1, 6.04], 
 'list1': [more, list, values, here], ...], ...
}
```

**covariance matrix method 1: `numpy`**

You can stack your 41 lists contained in your dictionary `d` and then use [`np.cov`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html#numpy.cov).

```
import numpy as np

all_ls = np.vstack(d.values())

cov_mat = np.cov(all_ls)
```

Which will then return your covariance matrix

**Covariance matrix Method 2: `pandas`**:

You can also use [`pandas.cov`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cov.html) to get the same covariance matrix, if you prefer to have it in `pandas` tabular format for later:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame(d)

cov_mat = df.cov()
```

**Minimal example**

If you had a `txt` file that looked like:

```
2010.36 23.2628 59.7768 1.0 4.1 6.04
2018.36 29.2    84  2.0 8.1 6.24
2022.36 33.8    99  3.0 16.2    6.5
```

The result of **method 1** would give you:

```
array([[ 661506.97804414,  662002.706604  ,  661506.6953528 ],
       [ 662002.706604  ,  662576.37510667,  662123.94745333],
       [ 661506.6953528 ,  662123.94745333,  661701.07526667]])
```

and **method 2** would give you:

```
               list0          list1          list2
list0  661506.978044  662002.706604  661506.695353
list1  662002.706604  662576.375107  662123.947453
list2  661506.695353  662123.947453  661701.075267
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a bit tricky how np.cov calculates the covariance matrix. By the [Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix) the element on the *i, j* position is the covariance between the *ith* and the *jth* features. As an example:

> the variation in a collection of random points in **two-dimensional** space cannot be characterized fully by a single number, nor would the variances in the x and y directions contain all of the necessary information; a **2×2 matrix** would be necessary to fully characterize the two-dimensional variation.

That said, since you have 6 dimensions, you should have a 6x6 matrix.

Following that, I did some research and found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45134122/numpy-cov-returns-unexpected-output) that uses the `rowvar=False` as shown bellow:

```
import numpy as np
l1 = [2010.36, 23.2628, 59.7768, 1.0, 4.1, 6.04]
l2 = [2018.36, 29.2, 84, 2.0, 8.1, 6.24]
all_ls = np.vstack((l1,l2))
np.cov(all_ls, rowvar=False)
```

You can build your `all_ls` stacking as many `l's` as you have and the covariance matrix would still be a 6x6 matrix.

Additionally, you can note that the `np.cov` calculates the covariance for **all** pairs of variables passed as parameters. For a better understanding about it I recommend [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317822/calculating-covariance-with-python-and-numpy) question, which shows how the `np.cov` gets a 2x2 matrix from your input when you don't set the `rowvar=False`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the most pythonic way could be the following, using [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
import pandas as pd

file_path = "Input2010_5a.txt"
cov = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep='\t').cov()
```

In addition, if you'd like to visualise the matrix, you could use [`seaborn.heatmap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [40, 40]
plt.axis('scaled')
sns.heatmap(cov, 
        annot=True,
        cbar = False,
        fmt="0.2f",
        cmap="YlGnBu",
        xticklabels=range(len(cov)),
        yticklabels=range(len(cov)))
plt.title("Covariance matrix")
```

**Covariance matrix:**
The following matrix was generated using a randomize matrix of the same shape of your data, `(41, 6)`:

[image: Covariance matrix]